# Python log file Datestamp

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a program that insets a CSV file into a mysql database using Python.
Once the rows / columns of the CSV file have been inserted, the Python program creates a log file, calculates the number of rows and columns contained in the CSV file and logs this data.
As shown below

```
# Output the results to a Logfile

filename  = open("DailyLogFile.txt",'w')
sys.stdout = filename
print "The Number of Messages Exported To DataBase for this file was; "
# Calculate number of Rows and Columns 
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)

print rows
print columns

#close the logfile

filename.close()
```

Is there a way to add a Date or a timestamp to the log file so when the next CSV file is loaded into the database, the logfile is overwritten?

Comment: Please use the built in tools to format your code properly.

Comment: `filename = open("DailyLogFile.txt",'a')` will make sure that the log file is written in append mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comprehension is correct, you want to timestamp your file name in order to not overwrite it ? 
to generate a timestamp, you shall use datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime
```

then generate a timestamp when you create your log file

```
my_date = datetime.now()
timestamp = my_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%D_%H-%M-%S') # formatting YYYY-mm-DD_HH-MM-SS - you may format it a different way
# build your log file name
my_file_name = "DailyLogFile" + timestamp + ".txt"
filename = open(my_file_name,'w') ... etc.
```

For the different possible options, you may have a look to https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

use datetime module to add timestamp

```
from datetime import datetime
time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
filename1="DailyLogfile"+time_stamp+".txt"
filename = open(filename1,'w')
...The rest of your code
```